# TouchAction class object is performing the same operation again without accepting new arguments?

Tags: appium

Created object of TouchAction class

```
      TouchAction act=new TouchAction((MobileDriver<WebElement>)driver);  
      moveToXDirectionAt= (int) (endX * 0.7);
```

> act.press(startX,yAxis).moveTo(moveToXDirectionAt,yAxis).release().perform();
>           Thread.sleep(3000);

```
      moveToXDirectionAt = (int) (endX * 0.3);
```

// updated the arguments

> act.press(startX,yAxis).moveTo(moveToXDirectionAt,yAxis).release().perform();
>           Thread.sleep(3000);

Here I am trying to do two different seek operations using single object `act` of TouchAction class.

In the second call i have updated the arguments.

But appium is executing the second call same as first call. It is not seeking according to new arguments.

Comment: how you become sure that the new argument is not working as this is little difference of points?

Comment: I have seen the appium logs for both the commands.